# A cache friendly way to store data for threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

Some time ago I coded a 2D graphic and physic engine to play around a bit and now I came back to it to give it some performance optimizations (just for training).

At the moment I am thinking about some optimizations in the way I am storing and processing my data.

Basically, I am considering three approaches and would like to have some suggestions on them (or maybe even a better idea).

The data which is stored is accessed via multiple threads and very frequently.

I made a little and very simple (not working!) code example to show how the execution of my three approaches would work.

These are the classes and constructs I am using for this sample:

An enum with the direction on which a collision happened

```
enum direction
{
    up,
    down,
    left, 
    right,
    none //No collision
};
```

A class which stores physic properties and which has simple logic like calculating velocity etc.

```
class PhysicProperties
{
public:
    void calculateSpeedFromCollision(direction dir)
    {
        //Threadsafe!

        //Some calculations
    }

private:
    float m_Velocity;
    float m_Acceleration;
    float m_Mass;

    //Some other stuff
};
```

A class which stores collision properties and which can determin if 2 classes collide with eachother

```
class CollisionProperties
{
public:
    void checkCollision(Actor& actor)
    {
        bool collision = false;

        //check collision

        if(!collision)
        {
            m_CollisionDir = none;
        }
    }

    direction getDirOfLastCollision()
    {
        //Threadsafe!

        return m_CollisionDir;
    }

private:
    direction                         m_CollisionDir;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > m_CollisionBody;

    //Some other stuff
};
```

And an actor class which contains the Physic/CollisionProperties and additional to this things like GraphicProperties etc.

```
class Actor
{
public:
    void processCollision()
    {
        //Threadsafe!

        /*This function takes somewhat between 3 and 5 times the num of cpu cycles I need to 
        create a task + add task to pool + pool latency*/

        direction dir = m_Collision.getDirOfLastCollision(); //if no collision happened, dir = none

        if (dir != none)
        {
            m_Physics.calculateSpeedFromCollision(dir);
        }
    }

private:
    PhysicProperties    m_Physics;
    CollisionProperties m_Collision;
};
```

Ok now the 3 approaches I am considering:

In the first aproach the Actors are stored in a single vector and there is one task per physic calculation:

```
void doPhysic()
{   
    std::for_each(actors.begin(), actors.end(), [](Actor& actor)->void {m_Pool.run(actor, actor.processCollision); });
}
```

In the second approach the data is stored in one vector but the vector is split between n threads. This example is very static (for simplicity). I will code it more dynamic of course.

```
void doPhysic()
{   
    std::vector<Actor>::iterator begin1; // begin
    std::vector<Actor>::iterator end1;   // 1/4

    std::vector<Actor>::iterator begin2; // 1/4
    std::vector<Actor>::iterator end2;   // 2/4

    std::vector<Actor>::iterator begin3; // 2/4
    std::vector<Actor>::iterator end3;   // 3/4

    std::vector<Actor>::iterator begin4; // 3/4
    std::vector<Actor>::iterator end4;   // 4/4

    m_Pool.run(std::bind(std::for_each<std::vector<Actor>::iterator, void(*)(Actor&)>, begin1, end1, [](Actor& actor)->void { actor.processCollision(); }));
    m_Pool.run(std::bind(std::for_each<std::vector<Actor>::iterator, void(*)(Actor&)>, begin2, end2, [](Actor& actor)->void { actor.processCollision(); }));
    m_Pool.run(std::bind(std::for_each<std::vector<Actor>::iterator, void(*)(Actor&)>, begin3, end3, [](Actor& actor)->void { actor.processCollision(); }));

    std::for_each(begin4, end4, [](Actor& actor)->void { actor.processCollision(); });

    //Wait until 1-3 is done
}
```

In the third approach I would store the data in n vectors (one for each thread and sorted in a meaningful way ofc.)

```
void doPhysic()
{   
    m_Pool.run(std::bind(std::for_each<std::vector<Actor>::iterator, void(*)(Actor&)>, actors1.begin(), actors1.end(), [](Actor& actor)->void { actor.processCollision(); }));
    m_Pool.run(std::bind(std::for_each<std::vector<Actor>::iterator, void(*)(Actor&)>, actors2.begin(), actors2.end(), [](Actor& actor)->void { actor.processCollision(); }));
    m_Pool.run(std::bind(std::for_each<std::vector<Actor>::iterator, void(*)(Actor&)>, actors3.begin(), actors3.end(), [](Actor& actor)->void { actor.processCollision(); }));

    std::for_each(actors4.begin(), actors4.end(), [](Actor& actor)->void { actor.processCollision(); });

    //Wait until 1-3 is done
}
```

I could imagine that way 3 is the most cache friendly one since the different threads can prefetch data for themselfs and don't have to share a lot, futhermore the vectors won't grow to big and the vectors might even fit into the cache as a whole. On the other hand I am loosing some performance if I try to find a specific actor.

Approach 1 is not very cache friendly since the cores shouldn't be able to forecast which actor could be next, which means prefetching won't work on this.

Approach 2 should be a good compromise between 1 and 2 and is actually the one I favour.

Comment: While optimizing cache-usage is certainly beneficial, I hope it's not the first thing you do? The first thing you should to is to use a profiler to find some of the more obvious bottlenecks in the code, and try to optimize the worst offenders there first. Repeat until there's no more gains to be gotten, or when the code becomes to convoluted and unmaintainable. Remember to document and comment on the optimizations you do as well, since those tends to obfuscate code and make it harder to read and understand. After that you can continue with other optimizations. That's my recommendations.

Comment: Some programmer dude@ It's not the first thing I did. First I reduced the amount of locking calls I made, then I fixed my vector reserving that I use the optimal amount of memory in places where I can determin memory usage and as a third step, I improved my collision algorithm. The cach optimization is the particular point where some advice would be handy, since that's a relativ new area for me.

Comment: Well then, I would say you're doing great :). But cache-optimizations is one of the areas where I personally don't have any experience so unfortunately I can't help you any further.

Comment: When you split vectors between threads each thread handle only own part of vector?

Comment: @ivan kuklin yes, which thread is processing which part is determined by the pool but during the task runtime, the threads will only interact with their own vector part

Comment: @Some programmer dude alright, but thank you, even if already in use it's a good advice.

Comment: @Mango In this case approach 2 is best because threads almost not shre data. (Share only on border of chunks). Also i recommend you instead of, for example, storing `float m_Velocity;` etc in class store it in one big array in `class Actor`. Then you also can split this array between threads.